# Another pair of eyes for my date picking strategy?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

I'd like to group dates for a given week, with the starting day being what the user chooses in their preferences.
For example my preference may be that my work week starts on a Friday, and so Friday to Thursday should be my week.
Sunday-Saturday. Monday-Sunday, etc.

So I'd like to present the user with a date picker, and although they can pick any calendar day, I'd like to have the collection of
dates start with their starting day.

For example if I pick a random Wednesday next month, and my preferences are for a starting work week of Monday, then my collection of dates
should start at Monday. The code must be able to walk backwards 2 days, find that monday, then walk forwards until Sunday.

My strategy was to do just that - loop backwards until the start date is found and simply add 6 days to end on a Saturday.

Before I go about it this way, is there a better way (or maybe some sort of specifics in iOS that would make this easier for me than somewhere else)?

Answer (score 1):

Examine the `NSCalendar` class. In particular is the method: `setFirstWeekday:`.

Example code:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; // Or a date of your choice
NSLog(@"today: %@", today);

NSCalendar *caledar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[caledar setFirstWeekday:5]; // Sunday is 1
NSDate *beginningOfWeek;
[caledar rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit
           startDate:&beginningOfWeek
            interval:NULL
             forDate:today];
NSLog(@"beginningOfWeek: %@", beginningOfWeek);
```

NSLog output:

> today: 2014-07-22 14:45:01 +0000
>   beginningOfWeek: 2014-07-17 04:00:00 +0000

Comment: great thanks i'm so glad I asked! What do you think about the other answer above is it in line with what you were thinking, or would setFirstWeekday be a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `NSDateComponents`? You can specify a specific day of the week.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *pickedDateComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:pickedDate];
NSInteger saturday = 7; // In the Gregorian calendar, 1 is Sunday, 2 is Monday, etc..
NSDateComponents *daysUntilSaturdayComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
daysUntilSaturdayComponents.weekday = saturday - pickedDateComponents.weekday;
NSDate *saturdayAfterPickedDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:daysUntilSaturdayComponents toDate:pickedDate options:0];
```

Comment: Thank you - so in this case, it would be Saturday - "pickedDate" ?